# Произношение Щ в слове "полунощница"

Tags: фонетика

Известно, что в словах *всенощная*, *всенощное бдение* Щ рекомендуется произносить как Ш: [всенощная](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&all=x). Поэтому мне кажется естественным произносить близкое к нему слово *полунощница* (это тоже служба, которая совершается в районе полуночи или рано утром) так же, и я так и делаю. Но рекомендаций я не нашёл, поэтому решил спросить у этой аудитории, как правильно. :-)

Comment: Часто ли приходится употреблять это слово?

Comment: В монастыре, когда приезжаешь трудником туда, нередко. Даже если не ходишь на них. :D

Comment: Я понимаю, конечно, что неверующие его не употребляют или даже не знают, но всё же хочется знать, как правильно.

Comment: Задайте вопрос (может быть не напрямую — о произношении) о. Димитрию Смирнову в его блоге: http://www.dimitrysmirnov.ru/blog/

Comment: Знаете, он не лингвист, тоже может неправильно говорить. И вряд ли он даст аргументированный ответ.

Comment: Вы будете спрашивать не о женщине-полуночнице, ответит, будьте уверены. Вот лингвист (представил атеиста Доренко) точно не ответит.

Comment: Не понял логики, простите...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Artyom Lugovoy, я думаю вы правы. Слово полУнощница относится к церковной лексике, где сильно влияние церковнославянского языка (современного извода), а там такие слова чаще произносятся с твердым Ш. Эта тенденция укрепляется тем, что и в современном общелитературном русском (особенно в московском говоре) есть слова, где такое произношение рекомендуется или допустимо: помощник, булочная и т.д.

Словари, даже хорошие орфоэпические не всегда четко отслеживают правильность в отношении узкоспециальных терминов, с этим приходится считаться. Словарь же Зарвы - весьма достойный, на него вполне можно ориентироваться (хотя и в нем, вроде, есть отдельные неточности, это не должно смущать).

Но только не путайте со словом полуночница: там Ш как допустимый вариант, но не основной, как в булочная.

Comment: "Полуночница – отнимает сон у младенцев: ноченка-полуноченка, полуношница, полуношница-щекотанинка, полуношница-щекотунья, полуношница-бессоница".  А это, интересно, какая лексика?

Comment: Далевская, наверное)))

Comment: Спасибо! Я очень надеюсь, что Вы правы! :)

Comment: Только не понимаю, зачем моё имя уже не первый раз пишут с собачкой. :( Не сочтите за придирку, я понимаю, что Вы могли это неумышленно сделать, просто неприятно, когда так написано.

Comment: В таком применении @ не означает "собаку" (или то, что в разных странах приписывают символу); таков широко принятый в форумах способ адресовать пост или часть поста конкретному участнику. Почему именно этот символ (он обозначает предлог at) - отдельный вопрос.

Comment: А при чём тут *at*? Если бы было *to*, тогда ещё ладно. И то, при непосредственном обращении и to не подходит. А я сам при возможности непосредственно обращаюсь, редко пишу to.

Comment: Artyom Lugovoy, "@" принятый на данном ресурсе значок, который по замыслу разработчиков (еще прежней версии, сильно отличающейся от нынешней) должен распознаваться движком для передачи прямого сообщения адресату. Сейчас система это несколько видоизменилась, но традиция осталось, в каком-то виде система это ещё частично работает. Например, при использовании такого значка можно увидеть список подходящих ников - и выбрать нужный, не мучая себя точным написанием.

Comment: Действительно, можно. Спасибо, буду знать! Но я буду выбирать, а потом стирать "@". А мне и другим пускай уж пишут, как угодно. :))

Answer (score 2):

> Но рекомендаций я не нашёл...

Орфоэпическим словарём РАН

(*Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф.  **"Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты"** , М.: АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2012*)

рекомендуется такое произношение слова ***полунощница***:

***полУно[ш']ница***.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и идею! Я как-то краем слышал про орфоэпические словари и даже не знал, что **там** и надо такое смотреть. Всё-таки я хочу посмотреть ещё в других таких словарях. Один гружу онлайн — никак не грузится. Поэтому я долго не реагировал на Ваш ответ. Пока не убедился, что все словари так пишут, не могу принять ответ. Но ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В Яндекс словаре щ произносится так, как слышаться. Обратите внимание: “полунощница” устаревающий вариант. Современный - “полуночница”

Полуно́щница. I ж. устар. то же, что полуночница I II ж. устар. 1. Одно из вечерних богослужений православной церкви. 2. Молитвы, читаемые во время такого богослужения.

Толковый словарь Ефремовой

Comment: Не знаю, что такое "яндекс словарь". Разве это авторитетный источник?

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! Всё-таки хочется самостоятельно в этом убедиться. Почему же грамота рекомендует говорить [всеношная]? Наш настоятель и другой батюшка тоже так говорят. Как-то не хочется, чтобы всё это оказалось неправильным...

Comment: _Почему же грамота рекомендует говорить [всеношная]?_ === Так же рекомендует произносить слово _всенощная_ и словарь, на который я  дал ссылку в своём ответе.

Comment: Артем, я честно говоря, не понял ваше сомнение. Толковый словарь Ушакова, Ожегова, Зарва М.В. Русское словесное ударение, все эти словари рекомендуют произносить ''всенощная" ***[шн]*** В чем сомнение?

Comment: Просто я ваш ответ прочитал так: "все Щ (в любом слове) произносятся так, как слышатся". Виноват.) Кстати, сейчас сообразил, что такого точно не может быть из-за *помощника*.

Comment: Я рад тогда, что это слово никто не оспаривает.

Comment: Кстати, если будет вариант с ЧН, его можно будет читать, как ШН, выходит? Как булошная, например.

Comment: Конечно можно [шн] !

Comment: Не знаю, зачем лимит. С чем это связано. Артем, я удаляю свои комментарии. Здесь запрещены развернутые обсуждения.

Comment: Простите... Сложно как-то знать меру в этом... Я тоже удалил несколько.

Comment: _Серж: Обратите внимание: “полунощница” устаревающий вариант. Современный - “полуночница”._ === Серж, Вы **не правы!**  "ПолУнощница" и “полунОчница” -- слова с **разными** значениями!

Comment: Я тоже подумал, не имеется ли в виду полунОчница, т. е. женщина. А в слове полУнощница ударение на У. Просто у меня этих словарей нету, и я понятия не имею, что там реально написано, поэтому это могло быть только предположением.

Comment: Слава, я обновил свой ответ. А основе чего Вы считаете, что это слова с разными значениями? Ефремова так не считает.

Comment: _Серж: А на основе чего Вы считаете, что это слова с разными значениями?_ === Ориентировался на РОС, "Большой орфоэпический", "Полный церковно-славянский словарь" Дьяченко... Нигде _полунОчница_ (да ещё с ударением на "о"!) в значении "церк. служба" не встретилась. Почему у Ефремовой на Академике так -- не знаю. При случае посмотрю, что у неё в бумажном словаре.

Comment: Вы думаете, в словаре ошибка? К сожалению, у меня бумажной версии словаря. Я бы посмотрел. Буду ждать вашего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

У Резниченко: **полУночный и полунОчный**. **ЧН! Произноение ШН имеет архаичный характер:**

Но туман не шелохнется, Жду полУночной поры. Кто-то шепчет и смеется, И горят, горят костры (А. Блок).

О ветер полунОчный, Проснися! Будь мне друг! Схвати со дна колечко И выкати на луг (В. Жуковский).

Comment: Vera, вы не поняли. Речь о слове полУнощница. В нем произношение совсем не обязано как-то следовать за орофэпическми номами прилагательного. А уж произношение ЩН - в принципе не может за ними следовать. Сравните: "крёстный" и "крестный" - это два разных слова. Это далекая аналогия, но о она о том, что нельзя механически переносить нормы на другую сферу.

Comment: Да, я написал, что это служба, так что Вы просто неправильно поняли, о чём я.